# PHP file_get_contents does not work for some URLs

Tags: php, web-scraping

Why PHP's file_get_contents do not work for some URLs?

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('http://modagram.com');
?>
```

For above I receive this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://modagram.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in /var/www/html/scraping/test.php on line 2
```

Comment: can you confirm you have 'allow_url_fopen' set to ON in php.ini ?

Comment: allow_url_open is set to Yes, also it works for other urls, but not for http://modagram.com

Comment: @Glavić I looked at that thread, but there is solution not explanation

Comment: Perhaps modagram.com is blocking access for requests that aren't made by a browser in order to stop web scraping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @MarkBaker said in the comment, webserver is probably blocking unknown UserAgents, try to fake one:

```php
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)',
    ],
]);
$html = file_get_contents('http://modagram.com', false, $context);

print_r($http_response_header); // see response headers
```