# file_get_contents doesn't work on some url's

Tags: php, xml, rss, file-get-contents

I want to get a rrs feed using file_get_contents

```
$text = @file_get_contents("http://www.kalbam.lt/?feed=rss2");
```

But I have no idea why I don't get anything from this url (PS. with other rss feeds it works).
allow_url_open is on.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe remove the `@` and check your `error.log`? Do you have `error_reporting` set?

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631272/php-file-get-contents-does-not-work-for-some-urls).

Comment: error reporting set to E_ALL

Comment: cant see any errors.

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.kalbam.lt/?feed=rss2): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

when with example form @Jaydeep Mor with user_agent

Comment: @MatasLesinskas .. got it.. Your given url is gives `Your connection is not private` and its don't have certificate there for you get error,

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/n3qt-52th check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some services can simply check if the request is coming from a script or from the web browser. Then they can block the requests. But why not to create fake headers?!

```
$header=array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
'Host: adfoc.us',
'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
'Connection:keep-alive',
'Host:adfoc.us',
'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
);
```

and then use the curl to retrive the data.

Comment: Probably I will have to do something like this. Weird situation :P. I will try this.

Comment: Ok I found out how to do it :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-setting-request-headers